# Vue get recursive parent (preferably without Event Bus)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

We have a form similar to this:

```
<v-form v-model="valid" ref="form">
  <some-component1>
    <some-component2>
      <some-component3>
        <v-text-field @focus="fieldFocus" />
      </some-component>
    </some-component>
  </some-component>
</v-form>
```

which on focusing the text-field should reset the v-form's validationErrors. Right now I kinda got it working with the following:

```
methods: {
  fieldFocus () {
    if (this.parentForm) {
      this.parentForm.resetValidation()
    }
  }
},
computed: {
  parentForm () {
    let parent = this
    while (parent && parent.$parent) {
      parent = parent.$parent
      if (parent.$refs && parent.$refs.form) {
        return parent.$refs.form
      }
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

Well... It works and the computed is cached, so it shouldn't be *that* bad for performance. But of course I'd prefer to not use a while loop *shudder*

Is there ways to optimize this? Or what would the "Vue" way to do this be? I'd like to not use an Event Bus, as we don't have one in our app and it seems overkill just for this (unless you'd say it would be way better). Same with emitting events through layers and layers of components. Any help/ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good use for provide/inject. You can't modify v-form because it's not yours, but in your top level child component, you could do...

```
provide: { 'form': parent.$refs.form }
```

then in any child component that needs it...

```
inject: ['form']
...
this.form.resetValidation()
```

Comment: Nice, didn't really know provide/inject. Works perfectly for my use case, thanks so much.